# How to name ssh connection

Tags: linux, ssh

I have an SSH connection that I can open without password. I have to name that connection so I can use it like

```
ssh server
```

How could I do that?

Comment: you could use aliases for that, like alias ssh_server='ssh 127.0.0.1'. This alias is valid as long as your shell is open. If you want to make it persistent, put it in your .profile .

Comment: This is a good answer, but I have to name it to server in the config file or something like that.

Comment: @Arkanosis solution is working nicely, I just tried it out. I suggest you go with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host server
Hostname actualServerNameOrIp
User yourUserName
```

Of course, replace `server` with the name you want to type when you `ssh server`, `actualServerOrIp` with the actual server name or IP address and `yourUserName` with the name of the user you're allowed to login with on that server.